# Tracking stationary 2D footage to 3d marker/empties

Tags: tracking

I’ve got a project I want to tackle, I’m pretty new at tracking so I’m not sure of workflow and any advice would be appreciated. Basically I want to use a stationary 2d video of my son’s soccer game, track players and the ball, and then use that data to constrain those markers/empties to objects that I place on a 3d representation of the soccer field so that he and I can look at the 3d soccer field from different angles (top down, from the goalie’s perspective) and potentially track and view his speed and the speed of the ball.

What would be the best way to do this?